# Display the user whose request is pending at the top (Laravel - Pagination)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a panel displaying all user requests.

In the following my code:

```
    public function index(){
      $infos = PersonalInfo::latest()->simplePaginate();

      $rank = $infos->firstItem();
      return view('HR/dashboard',["infos"=>$infos, "rank"=>$rank]);
   }
```

In HR dashboard display all requests (personal infos) >>pending , approved and rejected request

I need to display the request whose status is pending at the top and then the other requests

I have no idea how to do this, so I need your help

Comment: How are you displaying the user requests? Edit your question add relevant codes to your questions. FYI, please see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL or MariaDB, you could try the following to define a custom sort order. It will order by your `status` column, but in the order of the statuses that are given.

```php
public function index()
{
    $infos = PersonalInfo::orderByRaw("FIELD(status, 'pending', 'approved', 'rejected')")
        ->simplePaginate();

    $rank = $infos->firstItem();
    
    return view('HR/dashboard',["infos"=>$infos, "rank"=>$rank]);
}
```